# Reading with xlrd in python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I wrote this program to read a column from an excel file then write it into a txt file:

```
import xlrd, sys

text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
isotope = xlrd.open_workbook(sys.argv[1])
first_sheet=isotope.sheet_by_index(0)
x= []
for rownum in range(first_sheet.nrows):
    x.append(first_sheet.cell(rownum, 1))

for item in x:
  text_file.write("%s\n" % item)

text_file.close()
```

It reads the column correctly but writes it like so:

```
number:517.0
number:531.0
number:517.0
number:520.0
number:513.0
number:514.0
number:522.0
```

Can I read it in a way that it just writes the value and not "number:"? I could just cut out the first 7 characters of every line, but that seems kind of inefficient.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: have you tried `item.value` ?

Comment: In a debugger, what do you get if you type `dir(item)`?

Comment: @muratgu `item.value` is exactly what I was looking for. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you want a way to read entire values of a row in one shot:

You can take first_sheet and do:

```
first_sheet.row_values(index_of_row)
```

This will return a list with all the values of the index_of_row.